# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

There are two local factories that produce radios. Each radio produced at factory $A$
is defective with probability $.05$, whereas each one produced at factory $B$ is defective
with probability $.01$. Suppose you purchase two radios that were produced at the
same factory, which is equally likely to have been either factory $A$ or factory $B$.  If the first radio that you check is defective, what is the conditional probability that
the other one is also defective?

I approached the given problem in the following way.

$$P(\text{Defective and }A)=0.05$$
$$P(\text{Defective and }B)=0.01$$

There is a $50\%$ chance that the radios are produced in either $A$ or $B$.
If the radios are produced in $A$ then, probability of one radio being defective is $P(\text{defective}|A)=\frac{P(\text{defective and }A)}{P(A)}$.
Now if this logical flow is correct, then how do I find the same for two radios given that one of them is defective?

Comment: You've misinterpreted the question. The probabilities you are given are the conditional probabilities $P(\text{Defective} | A)$ and $P(\text{Defective} | B)$.